# Get data from JSONB column using other column

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, jsonb

In my PostgreSQL database I have the following schema:

```
CREATE TABLE survey_results (
    id integer,
    domain_name varchar,
    scores jsonb DEFAULT '{}'::jsonb
);

INSERT INTO survey_results (id, domain_name, scores)
    VALUES (1, 'food_insecurity','{"medica": { "categories": { "food_insecurity": "low", "housing": "high"  } } }');

INSERT INTO survey_results (id, domain_name, scores)
    VALUES (2, 'housing','{"medica": { "categories": { "food_insecurity": "low", "housing": "high"  } } }');
```

Now I want to have sql query with one additional column. This column should get score from `scores#>>'{medica, categories}'` using domain_name column value, so the results should be following:

```
    id         | domain_score
----------------------------------
    1          | low
    2          | high
```

How can I do this in PostgreSQL?

Here is db fiddle with my db schema: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/i49SiaQn6qWcwiWDxVbHnn/2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `->` and `->>` [operators.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html) You can use a column name as an operand, e.g.:

```
select *, scores->'medica'->'categories'->>domain_name as domain_scores
from survey_results;
```

[Db-Fiddle.](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/i49SiaQn6qWcwiWDxVbHnn/7)